# Android: Getting the right data from one Activity to Another Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

Need some assistance, please. I am attempting to pass data from one activity to another, and I know, there are tons of examples of this, and I have achieved the basics of loading a ListActivity from the strings.xml and pulling the button .text from the button and passing it along to the next activity. However, what I need is to apply attribute data to the xml list and pass THAT instead; so on the receiving activity I can receive an id that correlates to what was clicked so I can pull the relevant data I want to display from the strings.xml.  OR just pass the data I want to display through putExtra. See code below:

-- Sending Activity --

```
onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 . . .
Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String keyword = o.toString();
 . . .
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity1.class);
String s = keyword;
Intent i = new Intent(activity.this, activity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("com.activity.Key", s);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
 . . .
```

-- Receiving Activity --

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 . . .
String data = null;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    data = extras.getString("com.activity.Key");
} else {
    data = "Extras Was Null";
}
 . . .
```

As you can see I am getting the text data from the button, which doesn't really help me get to the content that correlates to that button. I feel like I need to pass the Node's ID instead, but cannot figure it out. I feel as though I am right there, but am missing something.

By request, here is the XML I am inflating. I added the second array (content) so I may match the content to what was pressed in the ListActivity (root_menu); it is a work in progress...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, activity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Activity Tutorial</string>
<string-array name="root_menu">
    <item id="o1">Item 1</item>
    <item id="o2">Item 2</item>
    <item id="o3">Item 3</item>
    <item id="o4">Item 4</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="content">
    <item>Content for Item 1.</item>
    <item>Content for Item 2.</item>
    <item>Content for Item 3.</item>
    <item>Content for Item 4.</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Define for us, "the content that correlates to that button."

Comment: Lets say the menu item is "Click here for Lorem Ipsum", the correlating content would be paragraph(s) of lorem ipsum.

Comment: +1 for Maximus I don't fully understand the question

Comment: the View v is the item clicked in the list, set a Key on this and do String keyword = v.getKey();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the corresponding XML? By "button" you mean list item, correct? It sounds like you are trying to store data in the XML item nodes as attributes, correct?

Unfortunately I don't think that is supported by Android - the resource XML files are precompiled and cannot be modified from there, and I don't believe you can arbitrarily define new attributes to be retrieved either.

(However, what you *can* do if you only need to read (and not write to) resource XML is define new types of nodes, and retrieve their values accordingly (probably including attribute values, but I've yet to try it))...

However, this may not help you if all you're trying to do is retrieve the value of a list selection, which is usually done by just maintaining an array of values that match the list.

Let me know if I'm totally missing the point of your question.

**Edit:** Looks like you're just trying to find out which list item was clicked, as opposed to the content of that item. Use the "position" parameter of [onListItemClicked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) to get the index.

Comment: Here is the node I am inflating:

Comment: <string-array name="root_menu">
        <item id="o1">Item 1</item>
        <item id="o2">Item 2</item>
        <item id="o3">Item 3</item>
        <item id="o4">Item 4</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: Please post it in the original post.

Comment: I could set up an array of content data that matches the ListActivity array, but how do I get the listItem # i clicked on instead of the button text so I may match it to my data array?

Comment: Ah I gotcha now. See the position parameter in onListItemClick? That gives you the index that was clicked, just make sure your array indices match the list.

Comment: See "onListItemClick" in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Comment: Ah, it was stairing me right in the face. Simply Toast'ing the position returns the int value of button pressed. I guess the real fun starts now. I must parse the xml and display the correlating data on the receiving end. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Another question: Looking at my xml in the OP, would the ID parameter return my "ID" attribute the way that it is formatted?

Comment: No - I don't know how to set/retrieve custom attributes like that, but it's a question that's probably been asked here on SO somewhere. You might also save yourself some trouble by reading up on using Android XML resources in the developers guide.